# OpenGL windows always on top

Tags: ati, google-chrome, fglrx, webgl

In order to get webgl working on ubuntu I had to change some setting which somehow forced hardware acceleration to be turned on for a window. Unfortunately now all opengl viewports are always on top like an overlay and causes other annoying "overlay" glitches.

In any case I'm afraid I really can't remember what I did to break things and I don't know where I found that reference! Does anyone happen to have any ideas how I broke it or could fix it again?

I'm running the fglrx driver with ATI HD 5000 series card, Ubuntu 11.04. I'm also running ubuntu with the plain no effects classic gui.

Some glxinfo:

```
name of display: :0.0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: ATI
server glx version string: 1.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known issue with FGLRX and Ubuntu. I thought it only happened with Unity-2D but according to what you're saying it also happens with classic desktop. All OpenGL windows suffer from this problem. Take a look in here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-2d/+bug/800599
To disable webgl in Firefox you can type about:config in the address bar and search for webgl.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought that it was due to some strange setting but what you say makes sense. Maybe I'll switch back to Unity-3D (although I don't like it very much)