# Ubuntu SDK content window always on top

Tags: 14.04, graphics, virtualbox, ubuntu-sdk

Just getting started with the Ubuntu SDK, trying to get everything set up, and I'm running into a graphics bug that I can't find a resolution to, or even anyone else who seems to have the same problem. Basically, the main content window of the SDK (which I guess is actually Qt Creator) will not let ANYTHING draw over it, even when it does not have focus. It's even showing up on the [lock screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5oEi.jpg). The closest I've found to the same problem is [OpenGL windows always on top](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57216/opengl-windows-always-on-top), but I'm not using Unity-2D, so I don't know where to go from here.

This is getting to the point of being unusable, as I can't even use things like the options menu for Qt Creator because it's drawing over those unless I move the window after opening the dialog so that it stops drawing over it.

I'm running 14.04 LTS 64-bit, freshly installed on a VM inside Virtualbox within Mac OS X 10.9.5, with 3d acceleration enabled and functional, if that's any help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly you should turn off 3d acceleration. Don't know why, but just do it. It's solved same problem with my installation.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend expanding this answer to include an explanation of *how* to turn off 3D acceleration.

Comment: I think I tried that.  Unfortunately, I have long since given up trying to run it in a VM, and I don't have Virtualbox installed any more to let you know if that works.

Comment: It works, had same problem just yesterday. Tried few options and finally turned-off 3d acceleration.  Unfortunatelly can't say that version of virtualbox you used. I used 4.3.18